# 502 Bad gateway nginx ubuntu

Tags: nginx

i have problem to configure my server with laravel application i get the message 502 bad gateway nginx i tried to configure nginx conf but with no success.

server info:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu.
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.
Release:        16.04.
Codename:       xenial

nginx site-available default:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/horizonemail/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
   index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 159.65.91.237;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

Comment: “502 bad gateway” is an error displayed in the browser of visitors to your site. As a server admin you have more tools at your disposal than normal visitors of your site and and after seeing a browser error  (which is typically not very informative by design) you should look at the (error) logs of your server, which usually will contain more useful and descriptive diagnostic errors. - for starters is there actually a FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000 ?

Answer (score 0):

is working when i changed line listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock in etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf to match with this  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;